# How to create a reusable piece of HTML with dynamic contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a reusable fragment of HTML that I'd like to be able to accept additional HTML as some sort of parameter.

My reusable code is

```
<div class="dialog" id="@Model.HtmlId">

  <!-- My reusable code needs to go here -->
</div>
```

Creating a partial view is easy, but the problem is that partial views accept a Model as a parameter.

My current solution is ugly.

```
@Html.Partial("_startDialog", new { HtmlId="someIdGoesHere" });

<form>
  <!-- Some form elements go here -->
</form>

@Html.Partial("_endDialog");
```

This renders

```
<div class="dialog" id="@Model.HtmlId">

  <form>
    <!-- Some form elements go here -->
  </form>
</div>
```

How can I stream line this. Elegance would be nice :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public class MvcDialog : IDisposable
{
    public MvcDialog(ViewContext context, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes;

        Begin();
    }

    private ViewContext context;
    private IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes;
    private TagBuilder tag;
    private bool disposed;

    protected virtual void Begin()
    {
        tag = new TagBuilder("div");
        tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        tag.AddCssClass("dialog");

        context.Writer.Write(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    }

    public virtual void End()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            disposed = true;
            context.Writer.Write(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public static class MvcDialogExtensions
{
    public static MvcDialog Dialog(this HtmlHelper self)
    {
        return Dialog(self, new RouteValueDictionary());
    }
    public static MvcDialog Dialog(this HtmlHelper self, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return Dialog(self, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }
    public static MvcDialog Dialog(this HtmlHelper self, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        return new MvcDialog(self.ViewContext, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@using (Html.Dialog(new { id = "mightyDialog" }))
{
    <text>awesome content</text>
}
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, that solution works great for plain text, but if you try <text><form><input type='text'></form></text> instead of <text></text>, then it stops working :-( Excellent answer though.

Comment: You don't need `<text>` when your content starts with html tag. However it should (and it does for me) work anyway, could you post exact behavior you're getting?